# How to get UITableView current item index in UICollectionViewCell class

Tags: ios, swift

[App Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3z4A.png)

As you can see from the scheme I have `UITableView` and in `UITableViewCells` I have `UICollectionView`. The problem I face is that I can't get correct `UITableViewCell` number when I set text on labels in my `UICollectionView`

Here's how I'm trying to check which row of the UITableView currently there's:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ExploreTableViewCell
        
        cell.currentTableViewRow = indexPath.item
        
        return cell
}
```

}

And then I set the label values according to the `currentTableViewRow` variable which I created:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ExploreCollectionViewCell
    
    switch(currentTableViewRow) {
    
    case 1:
        
        cell.collectionTitle.text = Const.newCollection.subCollections[indexPath.item]
        
    case 2:
        
        cell.collectionTitle.text = Const.freeCollection.subCollections[indexPath.item]
        
    case 3:
        
        cell.collectionTitle.text = Const.mostLikedCollection.subCollections[indexPath.item]
        
    case 4:
        
        cell.collectionTitle.text = Const.healthFitnessCollection.subCollections[indexPath.item]
        
    case 5:
        
        cell.collectionTitle.text = Const.earthCollection.subCollections[indexPath.item]
        
    default:
        
        cell.collectionTitle.text = Const.autumnEditionCollection.subCollections[indexPath.item]
    
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

Also, I `reloadData()` of my `UITableView` in my `viewDidAppear()`

I think the problem is that cells are **reusable** and that's why first 4 rows of my UITableView are correct and the other ones not. Any suggestions?

Comment: First of all, you don't need to reloadData() of your tableview inside viewDidAppear()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add function inside `UITableViewCell` :

```
func reloadCollectionView() -> Void {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ExploreTableViewCell
    
    cell.currentTableViewRow = indexPath.item

    cell.reloadCollectionView()
    
    return cell
}
```